# Multibyte StrLen? (StrLen for chinese characters)

Tags: unicode, strings, chinese

I am currently using `\StrLen{#1}` inside my `\newcommand`. This works flawlessly for any common string written in latin alphabet.

"Hello" has string length of 5 for example.
Problem is with chinese characters. String length of "容容" is 8 which is technically corrent, but I wasn't able to find multibyte alternative to StrLen which would return 2.

Note: I am using pdflatex.

Regards, 
Jan

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: if you used luatex or xetex then each unicode character would be a single token otherwise you need to count character tokens ignoring any above hex 80 and less than hex C0

Comment: Can you please show *how* and *why* you're using `\StrLen`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can count the utf-8 start bytes so for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{\zzz0#1\relax}
\def\zzz#1#2{%
\ifx\relax#2 \the\numexpr#1\relax
\else
\expandafter\zzz\expandafter{%
  \the\numexpr(#1+\ifnum\expandafter`\string#2<"80 1\else \ifnum\expandafter`\string#2>"BF 1 \else 0 \fi\fi
  \expandafter)\expandafter\relax\expandafter}%
\fi}
\begin{document}

\zz{容容}

\zz{abc}

\zz{¢Àïα}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I need. Tested and it works!

Comment: Note that this gives codepoints, not graphemes. These will be the same on PDFTeX (which does not support combining characters), but not necessarily in LuaTeX or XeTeX.

Comment: @Davislor true although that is what (some) definitions of string length for a unicode string would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\zz[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(utf8.len("#1"))}}
\begin{document}
\zz{Hello}, \zz{容容}, \zz{¢Àïα}
\end{document}
```

If your TeX distribution is quite old (say, at least 4 years old as of late-2020), simply replace `utf8.len` with `unicode.utf8.len` to get the code to run.